# How to use TCA Placeholder from parent records

Tags: typo3

Can anyone give me a hint how to use the TCA placeholder stuff correctly?
I got the example about `sys_file_reference` [here](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Columns/Input/Index.html#placeholder), but it doesn't work if I adapt it onto my TCA table configuration
My config looks something like this:

```
tx_epproducts_domain_model_product => [
  ctrl ...
  columns => [
    parent => [
      label => ...
      config => [
        type => select
        foreign_table => tx_epproducts_domain_model_product
        foreign_table_where => AND tx_epproducts_domain_model_product.uid != ###THIS_UID###
      ]
    ],
    name => [
      label => ...
      config => [
        type => input
        placeholder => __row|parent|name
        mode => useOrOverridePlaceholder
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

I thought I had to write `__row` to reference the current record, then `parent` to reference the parent record by the value inside the current records `parent` field and then the field where the placeholder text is located, but this isn't working at all.

I even don't get the checkbox to override the value like in the `sys_file_reference` inline relations

**EDIT:**
I forgot to mention that I want to use this in columnsOverrides section of another type of the record.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, this configuration is not fixable, yet. The configuration works for the `columns` section but fails to work in the `columnsOverrides` section of the type. This probably has to do with this bug/feature: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/76671

Long story short: placholder configuration is possible, but not via `columnsOverrides` in another record type configuration.